# Files not being created on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, rack, cedar

I host my [Jekyll-based blog](http://robinwinslow.herokuapp.com) ([github code](https://github.com/nottrobin/robin-blog/)) on a Heroku cedar stack.

I build the jekyll files through [my Rakefile](https://github.com/nottrobin/robin-blog/blob/master/Rakefile):

```rb
namespace :assets do
  desc 'Precompile assets'
  task :precompile do
    sh "bundle exec sass --update _scss:_css --style compressed"
    sh "bundle exec jekyll"
  end
end
```

This outputs the files into a `_site` directory, which is where Rack will serve the files from.

This has been working for over a year, and is working fine on the currently live version of my blog (released a fortnight ago):

```bsh
$ heroku run ls _site                                                                                                 
Running `ls _site` attached to terminal... up, run.9360
2012  404  apple-touch-icon.png  back-end  css          front-end  index.html  politics    public-domain.txt  rss.xml
2013  410  assets                config    favicon.ico  go.sh      personal    postsbytag  robots.txt         sitemap.xml
```

However, whenever I try to release anything now, or release the same version of the code to a [new app](http://robinwinslow-dev.herokuapp.com/), the `_site` directory doesn't seem to be created:

```bsh
$ git push git push git@heroku.com:robinwinslow-dev.git
...
http://robinwinslow-dev.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
...
$ heroku run ls _site --app robinwinslow-dev
Running `ls _site` attached to terminal... up, run.2577
ls: cannot access _site: No such file or directory
```

And the [site shows](http://robinwinslow-dev.herokuapp.com/):

```
Internal Server Error
No such file or directory - _site/404/index.html
```

Does anyone know why this would have changed? Has anything changed in Heroku? Or have I suddenly done something stupid?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this ever worked in the first place, because [Heroku has a read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). The solution would be to compile your site including all assets locally, check them into Git and then push the complete _site directory to Heroku.

Comment: That article says right at the top: "This article applies to apps on the Bamboo stack. For the most recent stack, Cedar, see the note on the ephemeral writeable filesystem.". I'm using the Cedar stack, so the filesystem should be ephemeral - so as long as Rake is run (as it should be) whenever the dyno spins up, the files should be there.

Comment: "During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted."